# Getting lat and lng for google map without using javascript in android

Tags: android, google-maps, maps, latitude-longitude

How to get lat and lng of a location on a google map of the center of the screen without using javascript.
I have been trying to find this answer for a long time.
Is there anyway?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Point point = new Point();
point.set(x, y);
LatLng latLng = mMap.getProjection().fromScreenLocation(p);
```

You can find your x and y by calculate screenWidth/2 and screenHeight/2

Comment: How to toast the value of latLng?

Comment: Toast.makeText(context, latLng.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();